# How to hide application key in page.js file of Windows Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure-mobile-services

In the Azure portal Getting Started HTML5/JavaScript sample that comes with Windows Azure Mobile Services, the page.js file has this line where the application key is visible -

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://somedomain.azure-mobile.net/', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx75'),
todoItemTable = client.getTable('todoitem');
```

How can this key be concealed so that it is not misused while still getting the app to run?

Answer (score 2):

The application key is not meant to be a security mechanism once your app, or website, is publicly available.  You can obfuscate it but you can't really conceal it.  If you need to have any security, you really need to switch over to authenticating your users.